# Does $U(f,P_n)$ converge to $\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ if $\lambda(P_n)\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function on $[a,b]$ and $(P_n)$ a sequence of partitions such that $\lambda(P_n)\to 0$. Is 
>   $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}U(f,P_n)=\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x~?$$

**Attempt.** In case $f$ is continuous, the answer is yes. Maximums of $f$ are attained on the closed bounded intevals defined by $P_n's$, so:

$$U(f,P_n)=R(f,P_n,K_n)$$

where $R(f,P_n,K_n)$ stands for the Riemann sum defined by partition 
$P_n$ and choise $K_n$ of points of $P_n$, so $U(f,P_n)=R(f,P_n,K_n)\to \int\limits_a^bf$.

But what happens in the case $f$ is integrable, but not continuous?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Just to be clear, is $\lambda(P_n)$ the length of the largest subinterval in partition $P_n$? Also, is integrability defined in terms of a Darboux integral? Namely, $f$ is integrable if the infimum of the upper sums is equal to the supremum of the lower sums?

Comment: The result is true. You can prove it using the result that upper sums can be made arbitrarily close to integral value if partition of sufficiently small mesh is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Using the guideline by @Paramanand Singh, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For all $k$
we can find $\xi_k^{(n)}$ such that 
$$\sup_{x\in [x_k^{(n)},x_{k+1}^{(n)}]}f(x)-\frac{1}{n}<f(\xi_k^{(n)})\leqslant \sup_{x\in [x_k^{(n)},x_{k+1}^{(n)}]}f(x), $$
where  $[x_k^{(n)},x_{k+1}^{(n)}]$ is an interval defined by partition $P_n$. Then 
$$U(f,P_n)-\frac{1}{n}<R(f,P_n,K_n)\leqslant U(f,P_n),$$
or:
$$ R(f,P_n,K_n)\leqslant U(f,P_n)<R(f,P_n,K_n)+\frac{1}{n}.$$
Since $R(f,P_n,K_n) \to \int\limits_a^bf$, we get $U(f,P_n) \to \int\limits_a^bf.$